# How do I compare every element in a multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I would appreciate any help with this.

This has been edited to more clearly describe how the array should be evaluated.

I am trying to figure out how I can compare all elements of a multidimensional array to determine if the elements comprise a true set.

Criteria

1. I won't know how big the array is going to be ahead of time (could be 2, could be 1000).
2. Each array element has two characteristics (color and type) that need to be compared.
3. If any charactistic value is shared by any two elements then all elements must share that characteristic value.
4. The values for 'color' & 'type' can be compared as straight text, they will match or not, no variation will be possible. I.e. Green != Greene.
5. The function only needs to return true or false based on whether is it a true set or not.
6. Any assistance can be given in JavaScript, PHP, or C. I can extrapolate.

Array Example

```
var obj = {  
    'Element001' : {  
        'ID' : 'value',  
        'Color' : 'value',  
        'Type' : 'value'  
    },  
    'Element002' : {  
         'ID' : 'value',  
         'Color' : 'value',  
         'Type' : 'value'  
    }  
    ...  
};
```

Examples of how different arrays would evaluate.

The following array should evaluate to "TRUE" because all elements are red and no elements share a type.

```
var obj = {  
    'Element001' : {  'ID' : '1', 'Color' : 'red', 'Type' : 'b'  },  
    'Element002' : {  'ID' : '2', 'Color' : 'red',  'Type' : 'a'  }  
    'Element003' : {  'ID' : '21', 'Color' : 'red', 'Type' : 'c'  }  
};
```

The following array should evaluate to "TRUE" because all elements are of type "b" and no elements share a color.

```
var obj = {  
    'Element001' : {  'ID' : '1', 'Color' : 'red', 'Type' : 'b'  },  
    'Element002' : {  'ID' : '2', 'Color' : 'blue', 'Type' : 'b'  }  
    'Element003' : {  'ID' : '21', 'Color' : 'green', 'Type' : 'b'  }  
};
```

The following array should evaluate to "TRUE" because all elements are "blue" and all elements are of type "c".

```
var obj = {  
    'Element001' : {  'ID' : '1', 'Color' : 'blue',  'Type' : 'c'  },  
    'Element002' : {  'ID' : '2', 'Color' : 'blue',  'Type' : 'c'  }  
    'Element003' : {  'ID' : '21', 'Color' : 'blue',  'Type' : 'c'  }  
};
```

The following array should evaluate to "FALSE" because two elements share a color "red". Per rule: If any two elements share a characteristic they must all share it. Thus all elements would have to be red. Also in this example no elements share a type.  But even if they were all of type "a" it would still evaluate to "FALSE", because of the color attribute.

```
var obj = {  
    'Element001' : {  'ID' : '1', 'Color' : 'red', 'Type' : 'b'  },  
    'Element002' : {  'ID' : '2', 'Color' : 'red', 'Type' : 'a'  },  
    'Element003' : {  'ID' : '21', 'Color' : 'blue', 'Type' : 'c'  }  
};
```

Also another that would evaluate to "FALSE" is a set where no characteristic is shared.
Such as one like this...

```
var obj = {  
    'Element001' : {  'ID' : '1', 'Color' : 'red', 'Type' : 'b'  },  
    'Element002' : {  'ID' : '2', 'Color' : 'green', 'Type' : 'a'  },  
    'Element003' : {  'ID' : '21', 'Color' : 'blue', 'Type' : 'c'  }  
};
```

Comment: why not JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2) ?

Comment: May want to consider renaming your title to include nested json instead of multidimensional array.

Comment: @CIsForCookies Because he only wants to compare `Color` and `Type`. Not the entire object.

Comment: @ClsForCookies Sometimes, that can produce a false negative.

Comment: The format given isn't an actual array.  It is a nested object where the first level of properties uses a name that is more or less abused to suggest sequence.  Why not use an actual array of objects?

Comment: @Paul Can you please point to an example?

Comment: @ClsForCookies When this has bit me, the string representations are pretty long.  Don't think I can give you a reliable case.

Comment: To be clear about data structures, an array of objects would be declared in JS like this `var mylist = [ {id: 17, color: 'white', type: 'sheep'}, {id: 48, color: 'brown', type: 'cow'}]` . The square brackets indicate an array.

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure about long string representations but `JSON.stringify()` does rely on the order of properties being the same. Technically 2 objects are still the same even if the order is different. That's where it produces a false negative.

Comment: @ClsForCookies actually I found a short case in nodejs that fails JSON string comparison.  `a = {x:1, y:5}; b = {y:5, x:1}; JSON.stringify(a)===JSON.stringify(b)`  yields false although a,b are equivalent.  node version 7.8.0

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the valid and invalid inputs? I'm not sure if i understand the problem correctly. Especially pt.3 is not very clear

Comment: **sorting** would seem to be a prerequisite for this problem if the goal is to ensure there are no duplicates as typically a proper set has either 0 or 1 of an item.  Create a sorted list, and then scan adjacent objects to see if relevant properties match.  If no adjacent objects match, then there are no duplicates.  The OP needs to edit to indicate which properties matter.

Comment: This sounds a lot like a homework problem from a programming course, although it might not be.  I find the meaning of criteria (3) provided through the examples a bit surprising in conjunction with the terminology "determine if the elements comprise a true set".   It would be clearer to say "return true if criteria(3) is satisfied".  But a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)) is typically defined as having no repeated values.  The question could still use some editing to be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow Following Example

```js
var obj = {  
    'Element001' : {  
        'ID' : '1',  
        'Color' : 'Red',  
        'Type' : 'X'  
    },  
    'Element002' : {  
         'ID' : '2',  
         'Color' : 'Green',  
         'Type' : 'X'  
    }  
};

for(var x in obj){
    if(obj[x].Color=="Green")
    {
       console.log("ID : " +obj[x].ID+" has color Green");
    }
}
```

If you don't want like that then you can use this code

```js
var obj = {  
    'Element001' : {  'ID' : '1', 'Color' : 'red', 'Type' : 'b'  },  
    'Element002' : {  'ID' : '2', 'Color' : 'red',  'Type' : 'a'  },
    'Element003' : {  'ID' : '21', 'Color' : 'red', 'Type' : 'c'  }  
};

var Keys=Object.keys(obj);
var _color=obj[Keys[0]].Color;
var _type=obj[Keys[0]].Type;
var _isSameColor=true;
var _isSameType=true;
for(var x=1;x<Keys.length;x++){
    _isSameColor=_isSameColor&_color==obj[Keys[x]].Color;
    _isSameType=_isSameType&_type==obj[Keys[x]].Type;
}
console.log(_isSameColor);
console.log(_isSameType);
if(_isSameColor||_isSameType){
   alert("True");
}
else{
   alert("False");
}
```

Comment: Please explain more so I can give answer like that I am not getting what you want

Comment: I am not testing for a specific value. I will not know what the values might be. I have added examples. Thank you for your time.

Comment: try second Example It will be helpful like you want

Comment: I think you want like that. Please accept answer if you got solution

Comment: Sorry about taking a bit getting back to this. The second one is perfect. I can totally rewrite this in C and wrap it in a function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome glad you like solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use square bracket symbol : []

```js
var obj = [  
        'Element_1' : {  
            'ID' : '1',  
            'Color' : 'Red',  
            'Type' : 'X'  
        },  
        'Element_2' : {  
             'ID' : '2',  
             'Color' : 'Green',  
             'Type' : 'X'  
        }  
    ];

   for(var i = 0 ; i++ ;  i < obj.length){
    if(obj[i].Color=="Green") {
     console.log("ID : " +obj[i].ID+" has color Green");
    }
   }
```